# If there a function to count a cell if it’s blank or non- blank based on if it’s located with in cellls in a date range?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Criteria I need my formula based on:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 7/3/2021 |  |
| 2 | 7/5/2021 |  |
| 3 | July 1,2021 | 775 |
| 4 | July 2,2021 | 788 |
| 5 | July 3,2021 | 73738 |
| 6 | July 4,2021 | 73738 |
| 7 | July 5,2021 | 73738 |

1. if the column c is blank or has a number in it (doesn’t matter what number)
2. if the cell c corresponds with cell b if it is in between the dates in B1 & B2

so essentially there would be 3 cells counted in this instance

What I am doing is in column B i’m entering in all the days in the month. Then in B1(admission date) B2 ( discharge date) , In c I will write a value .
I want the formula to count the cells(C:C) (both blank and non blank) between admission date and discharge date that the patient was admitted for .

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842

Comment: please [edit] to include the complete sentence like the previously deleted post (the missing sentence make this post hard to understand..)

Comment: In VBA use the function `ISEMPTY()` to check for an empty cell.

Comment: The COUNTBLANK() function counts empty cells within a range, e.g. `=COUNTBLANK((C2:C6))`

Answer (score 0):

The function below counts the number of entries between B1 and B2 whether they are blank or not.

```
=COUNTIFS(B3:B7,">="&B1,B3:B7,"<="&B2)
```

The formula will return 3 for your example. Your question doesn't clarify how blank cells affect this count but more conditions could be added to it.